# convert whole List from Float to integer in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im new to Pandas. I have fetched some values from the database, created a dataframe and used this dataframe to create a pivot table. The problem i am facing is, that if i loop through the list, the integer values are per default floats. I want them to be integers.

so here is my code:

```
resTable = cur.fetchall()
colNames = cur.column_names


df = pd.DataFrame(resTable, columns = colNames)

result = dfTable.to_json(orient='split')
jsonResult = json.loads(result)


dataTable = jsonResult['data']

for dt in dataTable:
    print(dt)
```

the results i got from this loop are the following:

[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

[None, 1.0, None]

is there a way to parse each value to integer in pandas?
or to set the default to integer?
Thank you for help

Comment: Do you have some sample data to work with? This can happen if there are nulls or words in your column. It'll force the numbers to appear as float (when they are really string)

Comment: this is acutally what happened, you are right. i have some nulls in my lists, but i need to convert the values still to integers and "ignore" the nulls

Comment: could you replace the None with a 0? Otherwise your not going to be able to convert the floats into decimals since they share are shared with strings. Your best bet in the case would be to do a replace('.0','') That would at least remove the float part of the strings.

Comment: this helped me, the results are as expected... thank you

Comment: No problem! Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

use `apply` and `pandas.to_numeric` to convert your values and replace `NaN` values using `astype(int)`, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],[None, 1.0, None]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  NaN  1.0  NaN
```